# What do we mean by "Non-preemptive Kernel"?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, scheduling, multitasking

I am not able to understand the whole idea behind preemptive and non-preemptive kernel.

I know that Linux kernel is preemptive i.e it can preempt a task even as it executes in the kernel.

If I understand correctly isn't a task is process(right?) and if it is so then can we not kill a task when we want it ? And if we can do that then isn't all the tasks are preemptive in nature and so are all the kernels?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking

Comment: who is "we"? What is "*isn't a task is process*" supposed to mean?